# In VSCode, the Shift+Space Hotkey doesn't actually work when the typing caret is inside the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

This shortcut is suppose to Maximize or normalize the size of the terminal, but it only works when the mouse cursor is active outside the terminal.
**It doesn't work when the  typing caret is active inside the terminal.**
Is there a workaround?

Comment: I don't have that binding on mine on Linux, though I'm using Codium. What command does the shortcut correspond to? Check in the Keyboard Shortcuts menu. Also try running **Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting** (`workbench.action.toggleKeybindingsLog`), then try pressing the shortcut and see what happens. And the setting `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` might be relevant.

Comment: I also don't have `shift+space` as a default keybinding. Is this one you set up yourself? Also, what's the value of your `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell` setting?

Comment: Yes, it is set to `shift+space.` I reset it to the default binding, but it still behaves the same way. It looks like a bug or bad design in VSCode functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go To `Files > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` 
Search for: View: Toggle Maximized Panel 
Change The Keybind whatever you like
I set that to `Ctrl + Alt + 1`

for more information and more shortcuts see [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/mac-and-windows-vscode-keybindings-2/) link